# Setting up SSL property while sending an email c#

Tags: c#

Can any one suggest me the background code when selecting the following while sending an email.

I have two check boxes 1.This server requires an encrypted connection 2.My SMTP server requires authentication. So my question is what is the difference between these two(in code part).

Comment: Looks like your server requires an encrypted connection.

Comment: There are dozens of similar questions, some especially about GMail, that it's hard to pick a duplicate. In any case, you don't provide any information or code, so it's impossible to guess what's wrong.

Comment: I have two check boxes

1.This server requires an encrypted connection
2.My SMTP server requires authentication.
So my question is what is the difference between these two(in code part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable SSL in your `SMTPClient` object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl(v=vs.110).aspx

Example:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("SMTP connection details");
client.EnableSSL = true;
```

Comment: That's not enough, but there are already a lot of duplicate answers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yep, more than likely there will be other errors, and it's pretty obvious the OP hasn't done any research, but this answers the question as asked.

Comment: And increases the noise level. There's a reason duplicate questions aren't welcome - it makes finding a good answer *harder*